# What has become of the user Joseph user:25814?

Tags: discussion

What has become of the user @Joseph user:25814 https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/25814/joseph?

And how is the community prepared to behave in such cases?

Comment: _how is the community prepared to behave in such cases?_ - What kind of behaviour and what kind of cases are you referring to?  Users come and go as availability/career/desire etc change.  I'm not really sure what you're asking in your second sentence.

Comment: Is the user who gave his time, his knowledge and skills not worthy at least mutual respect and human attention or the user is no one and no one cares about anyone? Then it is not development, but underdevelopment.

Comment: I worry that @Joseph, who has been an amazing contributor to this site, may be deceased, but I do not know if that is the case.  In any event, I do not know them personally and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38742/how-should-a-users-death-be-handled guides me in how to react to that possibility from a site perspective.

Comment: I agree, @Joseph is an incredible contributor and I do hope we hear from him in the near future. I have seen many regular contributors leave the site over the years--some due to job changes, others due to frustration, and others just mysteriously vanish. This site is designed with anonymity in mind, which can be good and bad at the same time, including for some of the reasons you highlight. Unless someone has contact info in their profile, the only way to get someone's attention is to ping them in the comments section.

Comment: Is it by purpose that there is no private message function? Would be handy sometimes.

Comment: @Babel - it is by design - see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user/433#433

Answer (score 4):

We should do nothing. That is just sometimes the answer. I left the site for a few years and closed my account. I would not want someone messaging me from the site during this time. I certainly wish @Joseph well.

Comment: Your story is a bit different and it makes me think that it would be nice to add some kind of sign on your avatar like "please don't disturb me" or "I need to be alone" or "went into hibernation" but you are back and good for you :-).

Answer (score 3):

I worry that @Joseph, who has been an amazing contributor to this site, may be deceased, but I do not know if that is the case.  In any event, I do not know them personally and [How should a user's death be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38742/how-should-a-users-death-be-handled) guides me in how to react to that possibility from a site perspective.

I note that @Joseph has not been seen on this site since 20 Mar 2020 after being a near daily presence for about 6 years prior to that.

Comment: The link to the question 11 years ago, similar in meaning to the question I asked, but what bothers me is that there are still no solutions to it. If there is a link to the user or his family members who can confirm the user's departure from life for various reasons with (email, his age, etc., or the user has not visited the site, for example 3 years) then in the left corner of the avatar you can place a mathematical sign of infinity - ∞ , and in the right corner place a sign of a contributor to the development of the community... 

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)

Comment: @CyrilMikhalchenko For anything like that you would need to try and revive the question on Meta SE, perhaps by placing a bounty on it, or asking a new question there that you could convince that community was not a duplicate of the 11 years old one.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, maybe I'll be ripe for that action someday..